# Difference between independence of events and independence of random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

I was wondering if someone could shed some light on the difference between independence of random variables and independence of events. The definitions look similar to me, but I am wondering if there are any conceptual differences between the two?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation is this: let $X,Y:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ two random variables. Then $X$ and $Y$ are independent if and only if their [pre-image $\sigma $-algebras](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Pre-Image_Sigma-Algebra/Domain) are [independent](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Independent_Sigma-Algebras).

In short: every two events of the form $X^{-1}(A)$ and $Y^{-1}(B)$, for arbitrary measurable $A,B\subset  \mathbb{R}$, are independent.

Answer (score 1):

Events $A_1, \ldots, A_n$ are mutually independent if
$$P(\bigcap_{i \in S} A_i) = \prod_{i \in S} P(A_i)$$
for every subset $S \subseteq \{1,\ldots,n\}$. (In the case $n=2$, this is simply $P(A_1 \cap A_2) = P(A_1) P(A_2)$.)

---

The definition of independence of random variables *relies* on the definition of independence of events, which is probably why the definitions look similar to you. Random variables $X_1, \ldots, X_n$ are mutually independent if the events
$$\{X_1 \in E_1\}, \ldots, \{X_n \in E_n\}$$
are mutually independent for any measurable subsets $E_1, \ldots, E_n \subseteq \mathbb{R}$. (Equivalently, it suffices to check that $\{X_1 \le x_1\},\ldots,\{X_n \le x_n\}$ are mutually independent events for any real numbers $x_1, \ldots, x_n$.)